# Objective-C/Cocoa: How to set value for a readonly property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties

I found that some objects are defined so that a readonly property is set by an external object, somehow. For example, in:

```
// skview is an instance of SKView
// skscene is an instance of SKScene
[skview presentScene:skscene]
```

skscene's 'view' property, which is readonly, is set to skview.

How is this possible if property skview.view is readonly? How can this behaviour be implemented in custom objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you declare a property in you .h file and set it as `readonly`, you can redeclare it in the .m file (in the continuation category) as `readwrite`, so you can directly edit the value.

But that's just the clean way of doing things. You can also use KVC to be a bit more back-door about it and just call `setValue:forKey:` which bypasses any of the nice stuff you might have done to specify what you want to be public.

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html) for a description of what KVC will do to fulfil your request.

Then, if you get really desperate, you can use the Obj-C runtime to get direct access to the underlying instance variables.

Comment: Thank @Wain. But declaring the property in the .m file grants access to the setter within the .m file, not for external objects. In my example, I think the SKView object is not able to see the proprties declared in SKScene's .m file, right? SKView just sees the readonly property in SKScene's .h, right?

Comment: Technically, everything is available one way or another. Making the compiler happy is just one part of it. If you declare a category on another class and add a method there, the compiler is happy. It's what works at runtime that's important, and that's pretty much any access you want...

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding this is to recognise the fundamental distinction between "interface" and "implementation".

The @interface defines the PUBLICLY VISIBLE face that your particular object wants to present.  To the outside world, it can declare that "this value is read-only, you may not change it".

Internally, however, the implementation is free to make it read-write, to directly access the backing store that the interface is exposing, or to implement the read-only property as a computation, something that does not represent a simple variable.

For example, imagine a property called 'firstSubview' - this readonly property would be implemented by retrieving the list of all subviews, then returning the first in the array (or nil if there were none).  Making this property writeable would make little sense.

Remember, an @implementation can redefine properties to be readwrite, can create its own private properties (and backing variables), etc.

Think of the contents of the .h file as primarily being for everyone EXCEPT the actual implementing .m

Comment: I believe you didn't understand the question. In the example I am referring to, SKScene's 'view' readonly property is modified from the outside, by an external SKView object, not by the SKScene object itself. If you read the SKScene's documentation, you will realize that there is no public method that can let know an SKScene object that has to change his "view" property because it has been added to a SKView.

Comment: The fact that you can't see an accessor that lets you set the view in the public API does not mean that there is not a private category within SceneKit that provides that access.

When you call -[SKView presentScene:] it is quite possible for the framework to use private APIs to manage the information you refer to.

I repeat my previous assertion - @interface only need to expose the PUBLIC apis that you are allowed to mess with.  And frameworks do not need to expose all of their internal workings to you.

Comment: Thanks, but still you don't understand my question: I was not asking for an explanation of what happens, as I already know this. What I was asking is how to implement it.

Comment: Inside SKView, you can declare a category on SKScene that promotes the property from readonly to readwrite (assuming that the property is actually implemented as something with backing store).

I have done this with a lot of framework classes.  Have a "framework-private.h" file which is imported into all of the implementations that exposes the "internal APIs" that no-one is support to know about.  Classes within the framework share secret knowledge but thats ok.

It really is fairly simple, once you understand that an @interface can be spread across many files, including hard-coded inside a .m

Comment: Of course, you can't just "declare a property to be readwrite" and hope that the plumbing is already in place - your framework sources all have to be written in a cooperative manner.  But your internal headers can expose a richer API than your public headers.

The other thing to watch out for here, of course, is that you have no idea whether 'view' really is a "simple property".  You can't easily tell from outside between a property that returns a value from backing store, from one that returns the result of a computation.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like external projects to set this property, then you need to declare a setter. So for instance you'd have in your .h file:

```
@property (readonly) NSString *mySpecialString;

-(void)setMySpecialString:(NSString*)string;
```

Then you need to write the implementation in your .m file and you can put whatever other operations you wanted to happen at the time of assignment in there as well. However, in this case there is no point in making this property readonly, as you can both read and write it.

One way to use readonly properties is to make them readable to external classes, then to modify the corresponding ivars in the .m file, so that they are written to privately.